# Unable to install .deb on Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: software-center, deb

I downloaded Dropbox .deb from https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx and the Google Voice Chat plugin from https://www.google.com/chat/video but when I click on the .deb files they open in Ubuntu Software Center. And when I click on install, nothing happens. The install button just turns grey.

I'm running 32 bit Ubuntu 12.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use gdebi to install your .deb files

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

and right click on your .deb file and open with gdebi

Answer (score 0):

open terminal by ctrl+alt+t. then type

```
 wget  https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx
```

then

```
dpkg -i Dropbox .deb
```

i think thats ok to you wrahool.

Comment: Thanks, but that isn't the link to the .deb file. I figured nevertheless.